# scraping a table with node.js doesnt show any result

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from [here](https://www.electionguide.org/elections/?inst=&cont=&yr=2021) with Node.js, however, nothing is showing up when I run js file with node.js.

I tried using this code with the Wikipedia table and it worked.
When I am using the same function in the console, I do get the list I need, but it doesn't work in node.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

async function main() {
 const result = await request.get("https://www.electionguide.org/elections/?inst=&cont=&yr=2021");
 const $ = cheerio.load(result);
  $("#datagrid > tbody > tr > td > a").each((index, element) => {
    console.log($(element).text());
  });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The data table body is filled by the javascript which run after loading the page, So Either you have to use selenium which loads the page first and then after certain timeout period, did the scraping or instead of scraping the data from html, try executing the javascript code in some way.

```js
<script>
        $('#datagrid').dataTable({
            
                "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
            

            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [10, 30, 50, 100, 200, 300],
            "iDisplayLength": 30,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sDom": '<"top"lfip>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">',
            
            
                "oSearch": {"sSearch": "2021"},
            
            
                "sAjaxSource":  '/ajax/election/',
            
            "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": false, "sClass": "my_class",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                if(data.match(/<img/g))
                {
                    return data;
                }
                else
                {
                    return '<img src="'+data+'" style="width:30px;">';
                }
                }},
              { "sClass": "my_class",
                "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                    try {
                        if(data.match(/href/g))
                            return data;
                    } catch (err) {
                        return '<a href="'+data[1]+'">'+data[0]+'</a>';
                    }
                 }},
              { "bSortable": false,
                "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                   try {
                        if(data.match(/href/g))
                            return data;
                    } catch (err) {
                        if(data[0]==null)
                        {
                            return '<a href="'+data[1]+'">Referendum</a>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return '<a href="'+data[1]+'">'+data[0]+'</a>';
                        }
                    }


                 }},
              { "asSorting": [ "desc", "asc" ], "sClass": "my_class" },
              { "sClass": "my_class" }
            ]});
        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search Elections...");
    </script>
```